# Getting my serial port to talk to my Adobe Air app

Tags: air, serial-port, byte

I have run into this issue where I needed a piece of simple medical equipment to output a string of comma separated numbers to my Adobe Air app.  I'm just thrilled to be talking to something besides a web service!

So, I got a USB to serial adapter, plugged into my computer, and used a program called [Cornflake](http://tomgerhardt.com/Cornflake/) to read this from the machine:

> 0,1,71.0,234.2,453,31.1,72.8,161.4,118.2,30,32.7,9336

Success!  So I do some googling and it seems that  [serproxy](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1140282379/5) is a handy tool that Arduino buffs are using to do exactly what I need:  serial to flash.  So I download, install, and config like so:

```
newlines_to_nils=false

serial_device1=/dev/cu.usbserial


comm_ports=1,2,3,4

comm_baud=2400
comm_databits=7
comm_stopbits=1
comm_parity=even

timeout=300

net_port1=5331 
...
```

These are the same settings that I used in Cornflake.  I plug in some simple actionscript to listen for an event, and when I catch the data event, I do this:

```
private function onSocketData(event:Event):void {
  var data:String = socket.readUTFBytes(socket.bytesAvailable);
  trace(data);
}
```

This outputs gibberish:

> ¬ ±¬·±.0¬²3´ .0¬´53¬3±. ±¬·².¸¬±6± .²¬±±¸.0¬3 0¬3².6¬93 3±

So I assume I am not reading the right encoding.  Seems like it should be ascii, so I do this:

```
var data:String = socket.readMultiByte(bytes.bytesAvailable, "us-ascii");
```

No dice.  So I start trying a bunch of different encodings and get the same gibberish.  I change the serial port to tty.usbserial, try flipping the newlines flag, all with the same results.  So, frustrated, I read the first couple of bytes to see what I'm getting out of serproxy:

```
trace(socket.readByte().toString());
```

It looks like I'm getting negitive numbers:

> 48 -84 -79 -84 -73 -79 46 48 -84 -78 51 -76 46 -78 -84 -76 53 48 -84 51 48 46 57 -84 -73 -78 46 -76 -84 -79 54 -79 46 -72 -84 -79 -79 -72 46 -76 -84 51 48 -84 51 -78 46 -73 -84 57 51 51 54 -115 10

Having no idea what this means, I hang my head in shame, and meander over to stackoverflow in the hopes that someone out there can teach me what I clearly never learned in serialports101.

[image: data]

**[SOLUTION]**

The issue I was having was that ActionScript has no way to read parity bits.  So, when it saw 10101100 (44 with even parity bit flipped), it read that as -84.  Now that may seem strange, as it did to me, so you'll want to [read all about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) on Wikipedia.

Now, to fix this strange issue, we simply need to be sure that **if** the parity bit is flipped to 1, we flip it back to zero.  Doing this is simple, because ActionScript reads the parity bit as a *negative* byte.

```
var text:String = "";
var tmp:int = socket.readByte();
var charCode:int code;
if(tmp < 0)  //check to see if the parity bit was flipped to 1
{
     code=tmp & 0x7F;  //reset the parity bit to 0
}
else
{
     code=tmp;  //nothing to do if parity bit is 0
}
text+=String.fromCharCode(code);
```

So there you have it.

**[/SOLUTION]**

Comment: I think i'm slowly figuring this out, as the config file from serproxy is giving me some strange results when changing it.

Comment: K, I'll post the code when I'm done, but it seems that ActionScript does a lovely job of reading bytes, and has no idea what a parity bit is.  Since I am feeding it parity bits, it has no idea what to do with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

48 decimal = 0 (zero)

so, you're one the right track; instead, print their numeric value (and spend some time on the parity bits too)

[edit]
note too that 46 decimal = . (period) 
54 decimal = 6 (six)
51 decimal = 3 (three)

finally, note that *0,1,71.0,234.2,453,31.1,72.8,161.4,118.2,30,32.7,9336* has a not coincidental connection to *±.0¬²3².6¬933..*

so you're actually quite a bit closer than you think.
[/edit]

Comment: Hmmm, I kinda get what you are saying about ascii codes.  46 = . gave that away.  Now what do parity bits have to do with things?

Comment: For example, change your settings to 8N1 (from 7E1) - it (kind of) looks like your only getting every 7th or 8th byte correct, the others are wrong, which leads me towards invalid character sizes.  For example -84 = ffAC, but -ffBC is 44 (the character for comma) - that's a one bit difference

Comment: +1 for making me think.  But, I don't see the 'not coincidental connection' to my gibberish :)

Comment: the characters 3 6 933 are in both strings, so you're reading the data @ the right baud rate (probably) but your character size / parity / stop bits are not right.  Time to experiment.

Comment: Kevin you totally earned the win here.  I'm posting the answer once I get everything working.  Thanks for all your help though.  (the answer has to do with actionscript not expecting a parity bit and treating it as a sign bit).

Comment: Glad to have helped, these are the things we see over time (and never forget)